# Find e4x expression from the given xml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to extract the name of the video from the below xml. Can anyone help me to find the e4x expression for this?

```
 <response>
  <user_videos>
    <user_video id="722"
                 name="334c5b8a387c3fe79f72f3b4079d3734-www.mp4"
                 original_capacity="5150"
                 uploaded_date="2012-03-14 14:28:09"
                 status="200"
                 file_original_location="334c5b8a387c3fe79f72f3b4079d3734-www.mp4" />
  </user_videos>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml:XML = 
            <response>
                <user_videos>
                <user_video id="722"
                                     name="334c5b8a387c3fe79f72f3b4079d3734-www.mp4"
                                     original_capacity="5150"
                                     uploaded_date="2012-03-14 14:28:09"
                                     status="200"
                                     file_original_location="334c5b8a387c3fe79f72f3b4079d3734-www.mp4" />
                 </user_videos>
                 </response>;



 var name:String = xml..@name;      
 trace(name);
```

You can reffer this also
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html

Answer (score 0):

The name should be read like this:

```
var videoName:String = xml.user_videos.user_video.@name;
```

**Update**

If you have more then 1 < user_video /> nodes then you need to parse the XMLList like below

```
var videos:XMLList = xml.user_videos.user_video;
var len:int        = videos.length();
var index:int;
var video:XML;

for(index = 0 ; index < len; index++)
{
    video = videos[index] as XML;

    var videoName:String = video.@name;
    trace("user_video["+index+"] = "+videoName);
}
```